# displaying preferences for a windowless (LSUIElement) app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

I'm making an application residing in status bar (near clock, power indicator and other icons). Yet, to let user change preferences I need to open a full-scale window.

However, since application is `LSUIElement`, it doesn't show on <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. It means that when user clicks on some other window, pref window will be moved behind and there's no easy way to get back to it. (You can fold windows one by one or use <kbd>F9</kbd>, but all this is kinda pain.)
So we have a useless dangling window in background and confused user ('where did my window go?').

Are there any better approaches to solving this task? Many similar utilities (e.g., [this](http://loganrockmore.com/MailUnreadMenu/) and [this](http://www.eternalstorms.at/gimmesometune/GimmeSomeTune/GimmeSomeTune.html)) have the same problem, and their authors are probably not greenhorns in OSX development, like me.

If anyone's interested, application in question is on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The standard way is to

(1) write a small helper Preferences app and add its preferences dictionary to your windowless app by NSUserDefaults addSuiteNamed: - this way your main app will have transparent access to preferences set in helper through NSUserDefaults API;

(2) use distributed notifications to notify your windowless app about preference changes.

Comment: It seems to be a tricky way. Can I package this preference app inside my main application, so user won't notice duplication?

Comment: Sure. Assuming main project is Newt and pref project is Preferences.xcodeproj:

(a). Drag Preferences.xcodeproj from Finder to Newt project in Xcode

(b). Open Targets/Newt info panel

(c). On General tab, add Preferences to Direct Dependencies

(d). For Newt target, create new "Copy Files" build phase and drag "Preferences.app" from Preferences project there (you'll need to build it at least once for it to show up, it'll be the only entry in Preferences sub-project in Xcode). Select "Wrapper" as Destination and "Contents/Helpers" as Path.

Sorry for the formatting, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it into Newt.PrefPane. Then it'd be accessible via System Preferences window. Other than that - I think Newt is awesome app and it's quite common to handle ui element apps' preferences this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since your user is not going to spend a lot of time on that preference pane anyway, wouldn't it be a good idea to make the preference pane always stay in front?
That's the approach big applications like Dropbox use.